# How to show content based on template file in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, angularjs

I am a newbie to angular js, In my web applictaion I have to display some content only on a specific page but I dont Know how to achieve it.

Here is my template of HTML (showContent.html), by this template my all pages are generating, and the url of my page where I just want to show content is `http://localhost/myapps/top/`

So I tried something like this:

```
<div ng-if="location.path() === '/top'" style="float:right;">

                    <button ng-click="toggle()">Week</button>
                    <button ng-click="toggle1()">Month</button>
                    <button ng-click="toggle2()">Year</button>
                    <button ng-click="toggle3()">All</button>{{post.id}}
                    </div>
```

but its not working and my content is totally hide by this condition. So how can I achieve in angular js to display my this content only on `http://localhost/myapps/top/` page.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `$routeProvider` [provided](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) by Angular. The routeProvider creates an association for each template-- you can associate the template, a controller, and other parameters (like view state, etc.). Check into the docs for more information, but the example below should be sufficient to fix your issue.

```
var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp', ['ngRoute'] );

yourApp.config(['$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider ) {

$routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'myapps/home.html',
        controller: 'someCtrl'
    })

    .when('/top', {
        templateUrl: 'myapps/top.html',
        controller: 'anotherCtrl'

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}])
```

***Note:*** You will also need to have an `ng-view` defined in your application (probably in your initial index.html file. You can only have one ng-view per application.

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

The controllers can be defined within the same JavaScript file, or in another file that is linked on the page via `<script src='yourScript.js'></script>`. Below is an example of how you would define a controller.

```
yourApp.controller('anotherCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', '$location',

    function( $scope, $http, $location ) {

         alert('You are now on a page using the anotherCtrl Controller!');  

}]);
```

***Another note***: One of the amazing things about Angular is [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), which is how we're supplying the `$scope`, `$http`, and `$location` arguments. As you get into angular, you should definitely check out the other services available. These services and directives are what Angular so great.

Comment: and how would I use `anotherctrl`

Comment: @Dinesh I've updated my answer. Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

check this two links. there you get explained how routes work in angularjs. routes are used f.e. to show different content on different urls

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07